# Guidelines for "shareable" url security

Tags: security, url, couchdb

I'm planning a webapp that will allow users to create resources without signing in. I plan on using the Google Docs / Pastebin style of security by creating unique hard-to-guess URLs. (e.g. example.com/ytasdfweoirue/)

What are some things to watch out for? What guidelines would you use in designing the token generator? What are some things I should consider? Is there a best set of characters to choose from?

My backend will likely be CouchDB, but I'm interested in platform agnostic, general guidelines and problems that might crop up in any platform.

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with this task? Are you trying to reduce the likelihood of someone guessing any particular URL?

Comment: Yes. I want to have some balance between short and secure and avoid any stupid mistakes I might make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use PRNG**

You should generate a random URL with a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), not with your framework's simplest Random() function. (*FYI In theory .NET GUID is not designed for security, in practice in a web app you should be fine, but you've been warned*)

**Do not include 3rd party resources in the "hidden" page**

Ensure that the page visitors visit do not include any 3rd party resources (javascripts, images, flash animations etc.) Pretty much all of them will leak the the current URL via REFERRER and your hidden URL will be exposed to all those 3rd parties. This is same even if you are using HTTPS and included URLs are using HTTPs.

**Do not include links to 3rd party websites, if you have to then take care of Referrers**

Again REFERRER leaking can be a problem if the page you are serving includes links to 3rd party URLs. In which case you can either redirect them from a common page (if you do so be careful about [Open Redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) vulnerabilities) or you can use a JavaScript trick to strip REFERRER.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your technology stack, but the best option here sounds like a Guid. Just have your url:

http://whatever.com/resource/{guid}

Guids are long enough to be hard / impossible to guess or enumerate and you have a pretty strong guarantee that you won't generate two guids that are the same. As long as you aren't in javascript, your language should have a guid generator available as a built in (.net) or a library.

Here is the wikipedia page for more discussion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier